# how to change a list from one format to another

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to change the format of a list using enum function.

The original list looks like this

```
myInitialList = 
[
 {1,
   [
     ["A3", "Teddy"],
     ["B3", "t@gmail.com"],
     ["C3", "56123456"],
     ["D3", "spain"]
   ]},
  {2,
   [
     ["A4", "Katrin"],
     ["B4", "m@yahoo.com"],
     ["C4", "85002145"],
     ["D4", "USA"]
   ]},
  {3,
   [
     ["A2", "name"],
     ["B2", "email"],
     ["C2", "phone"],
     ["D2", "country"]
   ]}
]
```

and I would like to filter the above list to have the below result

```
myFinalList = 
[
    %{
        name: "Teddy", 
        email: "t@gmail.com", 
        phone: "56123456", 
        country: "spain"
    }, 
    %{
        name: "Katrin", 
        email: "m@yahoo.com", 
        phone: "85002145", 
        country: "USA"
    }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can build the filter function?

This will allow me to easily insert the data in my database. I haven't really tried anything since I'm totally stuck from the beginning

in the code, it should look like

```
myFinalList = myInitialList |> Enum.filter(.....)
```

Comment: How would one know which group is supposed to be the keys in the result maps?  Are the keys always in group 3?  Can the keys be anything? Or, will they always be name, email, phone, country?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) function. Yo can get `myFinalList` with that format doing this:

```
myFinalList =
  Enum.map(myInitialList, fn
    {_index, [[_, name], [_, email], [_, phone], [_, country]]} ->
      %{
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        country: country
      }
  end)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would produce `%{name: "name", ...}` as the last element.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you need to split your input into names and actual values:

```
[names | items] = myInitialList |> Enum.reverse()
```

`items` here are in the reverse order, but it’s fine.

Now let’s define mapper:

```
mapper =
  fn {_, lists} -> Enum.map(lists, fn [_, e] -> e end) end
```

And, finally:

```
for values <- Enum.reverse(items),
  do: Enum.into(Enum.zip(mapper.(names), mapper.(values)), %{})
```